# Getting undefined when using $(selector).html()

Tags: jquery

I have this code to generate n amount of divs with id based on their x and y position:

```
    $("#gameContent").append($("<div></div>").attr("id", "board"));
    var card;
    for (var y = 0; y < clientBoard.length; y++) {
     for (var x = 0; x < clientBoard.length; x++) {
      if(clientBoard[y][x] == undefined){
       continue;
      }
      card = $("<div></div>").addClass("card");
      card.attr("id", (y + ":" + x));
      card.html("Value " + clientBoard[y][x].value);
      if (x == 0) {
       card.addClass("clearleft");
      }
      $("#board").append(card);
     }
    }
```

This works and when i inspect in chrome all divs have their correct (e.g "1:2").
Then I want to use the HTML() function to change the content of those divs. But when using:

```
    console.log($("#" + y + ":" + x).html());
```

It prints undefined

I will use this code to update the html content for the divs:

```
    for (var y = 0; y < clientBoard.length; y++) {
     for (var x = 0; x < clientBoard.length; x++) {
      if(clientBoard[y][x] == undefined){
       continue;
      }
      $("#" + y + ":" + x).html("Value: " + clientBoard[y][x].value);
     }
    }
```

I have tried to google and look at the documentation of the html(), but can't seem to find anything that is wrong. I used the html() earlier in my code, only difference is the selector there was just a string and not a combination of string and a variable. That worked great.

I also printed all the selectors it tried to use and compared them with the id of the divs, and they are correct.

I have also tested and printed the value that it tries to put into the divs, that also worked

Ask if I should provide more information.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get an error, as `:` is a special character and will need to be escaped in the selector.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason it didn't give me an error. I knew of some special characters, but obviously not all.

Comment: Hi, did you try making sure x and y are string instead while you using selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use an id with a colon in the selector you will need to escape it:

```
$('#1\\:2');
```